# Responsive Google Maps API v3 - Automatically display all markers on small screens

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, responsive-design, responsive

I'm designing a little webapp that includes `Google Maps API` in **Full Screen**. The webapp is intended to be used successfuly in **mobile devices** (even small devices). Actually I fetch some coordinates from my `Database` using `AJAX` and place them in the map.

I push the coordinates in an array `locations` using AJAX and then I do the following:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 11,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.262577, -115.8314989),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
  }
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    //locations[i][1] is lang
    //locations[i][2] is lng
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

How can I convert this script in responsive? I want to see all my Markers on the screen, mobile screens <= 768px (width), I can't find any generic handler  to smartly resize (zoom in/out) the map in order to view all markers in the screen.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is making a *LatLngBounds* object and extending it with every couple of coordinates you want to show. Then, just call *fitBounds()* on your map object, with your bounds as argument, like follows :

```js
var marker, i;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds()
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  var coords =  new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(locations[i][1]), parseFloat(locations[i][2]))
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    //locations[i][1] is lang
    //locations[i][2] is lng
    position: coords,
    map: map
  });
  
  bounds.extend(coords);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

If you want to apply only if needed, then you have to compare the variable bounds you created with map.getBounds(), by comparing their extremities : `getNorthEast()` and `getSouthWest()` coordinates.

Comment: I got this error: `InvalidValueError: not a LatLngBounds or LatLngBoundsLiteral: unknown property lat`

Comment: Are you sure none of `locations[i][1]` and `locations[i][2]` is undefined ? Arrays start at 0, so maybe what you are looking for is `locations[i][0]` and `locations[i][1]` ?

Comment: `locations[i][0]` is another information, like "Name" for being used in future in the infoWindow

Comment: And my code shows the markers, but there are some markers that are outside of the screen

Comment: My mistake, error corrected. It was `map.fitBounds(bounds)` instead of `coords`

Comment: Thanks, but now there is another issue: `InvalidValueError: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`

Comment: Just check `locations[i][1/2]` is a number and not a string. If it is, convert it using the `Number()` function.

Comment: Ok, they are `strings` I have changed the code in this way: `var coords =  new google.maps.LatLng(Number(locations[i][1]), Number(locations[i][2]))` but I still got the same error.

Comment: No, @Magix, that is not my problem, now I only see 1 of my markers, your code is wrong. My initial code works but don't make that I want (show all markers on the screen). The errors comes with your code, I will undo the changes. I should not mark this as the "solution" but I thumbs up the answer.

Comment: All of my markers are displayed on the map, that is the demonstration the my lat and lng objects works as intended

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139618/discussion-between-magix-and-alessadro).